# Is it possible to stop MassTransit service after a saga/consumer completes

Tags: azure, masstransit

So I know this runs a bit counter to MassTransit style, but I want to take advantage of some key features of MT such as message broker connection management, sagas, scheduled messages.

However, I know the service will be rarely used. This is a fairly large data take from an API which has a throttle of 12,000 requests per hour. Once every 24 hours a saga will start to take data and move it into Data Lake. The service will run for some minutes until the throttle is hit, then start again where it left off (state) when enough time has passed, maybe something like 30 minutes later. The amount of data means this will repeat for several hours (2 to 4).

The fit for a saga and and scheduled message seems pretty good. But it would be better if the service did not have incur operating costs for being awake 24x7. There will only ever be one request at a time for one set of API credentials. There may come a time when we might have multiple sets of credentials.

Is there a way to nicely close down the service when the saga completes?

As this is likely to be implemented with a container instance I propose to start an instance from a queue triggered function or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is the approach you want to take (versus just an Azure Web Job, triggered by Azure Scheduler), there are a number of options:

1. Publish an event when the saga completes, consume that event, use Task.Run() or whatever to stop the bus.
2. Use a receive observer to keep track of in-flight messages and when it reaches zero and stays there for *n* seconds, stop the bus, exit the function.

Though I wonder why not just use a scheduled job via Azure, seems easier unless MassTransit is being used for more than just scheduling.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, if it was just a scheduled job I think you are correct. But the process that is triggered by the schedule will run for a long time with several lengthy pauses and state that will change with pause/restart. The restart is governed by time based rule that will vary the timing of the restart. A scheduled message triggering the next event in a saga would seem to be a good match for this.

Of course, the other option we have is simply to not stop the service at all and leave it running waiting on the next start message.